# Forcing IPV6 connection to google?

Tags: ipv6

as per [Google over IPv6](http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/faq.html)

in order to connect to google through ipv6 the ISP must have some
sort of agreement with Google. my ISP does not however have such agreement

It was suggested that I do find the IPV6 IP for google and try to connect to
it directly, is that possible? and if yes how would one find the ipv6 for google?

For those who think that you can just randomly connect to google please look at:
[Requesting peering with google](http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/faq.html#request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

(1) Getting IPv6 connectivity to the Internet.
(2) Your ISP getting whitelisted by Google to receive AAAA records.

For point (1), your ISP must either provide you with an IPv6–enabled Internet connection, or you must sign up with a tunnel broker such as [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/) or [SixXS](http://sixxs.net/).

For point (2), that is something only your ISP can initiate. And it is only something they can initiate if they already provide IPv6 connectivity. In other words, (1) is a prerequisite of (2). However, if you use Hurricane Electric or [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/dnscache/), you may use their DNS caches, which are already whitelisted to receive AAAA records from Google.

Or, as poster borrel points out, you may simply visit http://ipv6.google.com/ if you wish. What you can even do a a little hack is get the IPv6 address of `ipv6.google.com`, and use your `/etc/hosts` file to point the other Google domains (e.g. `www.google.com`, `maps.google.com`) to that same IP. Your mileage may vary, but it worked for me last time I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

you need a tunnel broker form from for example he.net 
then you can reach google at http://ipv6.google.com [2a00:1450:8005::93]

and btw your isp not need a contract with google they need ipv6 connectivity, any isp can connect to ipv6 but manny not have ther infrasturcure not in place, so as a fallback you can use ipv6 over ipv4 tunnels so you can reatch tghe ipv6 network

Comment: did you not read this :  http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/faq.html#request

Comment: no i did not but they are talking about ipv6 for **WWW**.google.com (for isp's) and as a end-user you can use a tunnel-broker service, (you are not a isp you cannot peer with google), i posted the ip above ([2a00:1450:8005::93])